# Python 3 how to add text to chosen line in a txt document using append

Tags: python, file, python-3.x

In my document I would like to add scores to a chosen line using:

```
file = open('scores.txt', 'a')
```

because I don't want to add all the lines to a list and change that one line.
I'm basically asking if you can add something to `.write()` or `.writelines()` to choose the line that it writes onto. If not, any other ways? If not, maybe a simple way of adding to a list then changing a line.

basically what the txt document looks like:

```
User 1 scores:
15,
User 2 Scores:
20,
```

Comment: I have a feeling this might be an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) and that you may do well by looking into data serialization modules like [`json`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html) or [`pickle`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html#module-pickle)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to store data to store some kind of user informations is Serialization. You have several modules including Pickle (which serialize the object into a binary file, and later can deserialize this object by reading the file, giving you the exact same object as it was before serialization), or Json.

If you're looking for a good solution, but still want to be able to clearly read data (Since Pickle is storing the data as a binary entity object, you can't read it clearly), use JSON.

It's very simple for this basic use :

If you have for example this same structure as you showed before:

```
User 1 scores:
15,
User 2 scores:
20,
```

You can make it as a dictionary, for example like that:

```
scores = {
    'User 1': 15,
    'User 2': 20,
}
```

Which makes it even easier to edit and use, since to access the User 1 score, all you need to type is `scores['User 1']`.

Now, for the serialization part of this dictionary, to save it into a file, you can obtain a serialized string representing the dict using the `json.dumps(<your array>)` function. Used like that:

```
import json
dictionary = { 'User 1': 15, 'User 2': 20 }
print(json.dumps(dictionary))
```

The print will show you how it's represented. As a JSON compliant file.
You just need a simple `file.write()` to save it, and a `file.read()` to retrieve it.

(After test, using json.dumps on your example give me that: `{"User 2": 20, "User 1": 15}`)

To retrieve that data, you'll need to use the `json.loads(<json string>)` function.

```
import json
# As you can see, string representation of json.
dictionary = json.loads("{"User 2": 20, "User 1": 15}")
```

Your dict is now loaded & saved !

More infos on File IO here: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python3/python_files_io.htm

More infos on JSON Python native API here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html

Hope that helps !

EDIT:

For your information, Python native file IO module only give 1 function to change the position of the read buffer in the file, and that function is `file.seek()` function, that moves you into a specific byte in the file. (you need to pass the byte address as a function parameter, for example `file.seek(0, 0)` will position you at the beginning of the file).

You can get your position in the file using `file.tell()` function.